# search for integer (version number) in file using script

Tags: c, linux, shell, scripting

I have a file as given below, I need to access a particular string from the below given text file.

```
**  The gSOAP code generator for C and C++, soapcpp2 release 2.8.12
**  Copyright (C) 2000-2012, Robert van Engelen, Genivia Inc.
**  All Rights Reserved. This product is provided "as is", without any warranty.
**  The soapcpp2 tool is released under one of the following two licenses:
**  GPL or the commercial license by Genivia Inc.
```

How can i use shell script in order to get the number 2.8.12 from the above text file,

Comment: A simple regular expression should work.

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a program in AWK.  Put this in a text file, set execute permission on the text file, and run it with input from the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/gSOAP code generator/ {
    LAST = NF
    P1 = LAST - 1
    P2 = LAST - 2

    if ($P2 == "soapcpp2" && $P1 == "release")
        print $LAST
    }
```

I prefer Python these days, so here's a Python solution as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    if "gSOAP code generator" in line:
        lst = line.split()
        if lst[-3] == "soapcpp2" and lst[-2] == "release":
            print(lst[-1])
            break
```

If you put either program in a file called "foo" and save it, you can then do:

```
# chmod +x ./foo
# ./foo < file_to_search
```